# "bad decrypt" error while decrypting with openssl

Tags: shell-script, openssl

I have created 2 scripts to encrypt and decrypt a password inside a file.

The encryption script is as follow:

```
set -x
PFILE=/home/user/crypt/pfile
echo "changing PASSWORD"
P=`echo 'rawpassword' | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 1000 -salt -pass pass:'secret'`
sed -i "/PASSWORD=/ s|=.*|=${P}|" $PFILE
```

And the decrypt password is:

```
PFILE=/home/user/crypt/pfile

PASSWORD=$(sed -n 's|^PASSWORD=||p' $PFILE)
pass=`echo $PASSWORD | openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -md sha512 -pbkdf2 -iter 1000 -d -salt -pass pass:'secret'`

echo $pass
```

This decryption script shows the raw password successfully, but still gives me this error:

```
bad decrypt
140392493330880:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:../crypto/evp/evp_enc.c:526:
```

Does anyone knows what is causing this error?
Since he is decrypting successfully, I'm not sure what's missing.